# How to use a WCF Web Service in VB6

Tags: c#, vb6, wcfserviceclient

Situation is that I have a VB6 application and a WCF Service. The SOAP/WCF client has to be implemented in C# as we cannot do this in VB6.
So how can I use this client in my VB6 aplication? 
In simple words, how to use/consume a WCF WEb service VB6 Application?
The WCF Web service to be consumed is soap based.

Comment: You could use COM interop. C# assembly attributed to be callable with COM, and then export the typelib and call from VB6.

Comment: Dear Richard do you mean that 
1) Make a com callable library for wcf soap based client.
2) And use this library in VB6 project?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the COM SOAP client that Microsoft provides.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997641.aspx

```
dim SOAPClient
set SOAPClient = createobject("MSSOAP.SOAPClient")
```

Comment: This only shipped in the unsafe and unsupported Windows XP.  While long in the tooth now and also unsupported you can obtain a deployable version of this object as part of SOAP Toolkit 3.0.